# Firebase databases replication

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need a data from one Firebase project's database in 2 iOS apps (with different bundle names). So, the question is:

Is it possible to configure replication between 2 different Firebase project's databases? Or is it possible to use 1 Firebase project (1 database) for 2 ios apps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no built-in feature to replicate Firebase Databases.

I'm not aware of any tools that replicate between two Firebase Databases. The closest is probably making a backup from one database and restore to another, but it'll be a parent/child setup.

Yes, multiple iOS apps can talk to the same Firebase Database. Just click to add another app on your project's Firebase Console.

Comment: Backups can be configured daily - https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/10/announcing-automated-daily-backups-for-the-firebase-database.html. Then, use firebase-import - https://github.com/firebase/firebase-import to import that data