# Transfer data from one Firebase realtime database to another

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there a method to transfer data from one firebase realtime database to another one?

I have a project initialized and so does my friend and now I need to send data from my database to his. Is there a method that avoids http get and post requests and directly imports data from another database without any middle man?

Comment: I believe you'll be able to use [this script](https://gist.github.com/katowulf/6099042). Hopefully it still works with the latest Firebase version.

Comment: There is no direct database-to-database cloning in Firebase. See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38446883/firebase-databases-replication